# How can I appeal my Stack Overflow ban?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I assume I was banned for deleting two questions.
The reason they were deleted was because the community deemed them as possible duplicates.
I've tried answering questions to see if that would lift it but it appears not to be so.

Comment: You can appeal your ban until you're blue in the face. Problem is, it's not going to help you. The ban is automatic and nobody can lift if for you. The primary reference still is this question and its answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: @bart I've read that link about ten times however it is still of no help because my questions have been deleted. I cannot "fix" them.

Comment: You also have two closed questions and one with negative votes.

Comment: I don't know if they really deserved to be deleted (because I can't see them) and in no way could have been fixed to be appropriate questions. If you think they might have stood a chance with some work, perhaps a mod can have a look at them and link to them so you can at least edit them. But if that's not a possibility, all that remains to be done is answering questions and finding other ways to positively contribute.

Comment: @Bart Possibly. If there is a way to get unbanned by just answering questions I will gladly do that.

I'm kind of afraid of the Stackoverflow community after my little time there. They are very judgmental and hold no reserve towards their down votes. I guess it's safe to say, If I'm ever unbanned I will never ask another question again.

Comment: @TapThatApp Don't take SO personal. We do however uphold certain standards when it comes to the content we'll allow. You might consider that judgemental, but it also makes the site as good as it is. Do your best to improve and perhaps read up on how to ask good questions. It might take some work to get a grip on things, but it will be worth the effort in the end.

Comment: If you're never going to ask any more questions once unbanned then why do you need to be unbanned?

Comment: I guess I was being over dramatic. I'm only going to ask when it's an extreme emergency. Such as an unsolved project with a deadline.

Comment: @TapThatApp If you've never been linked to it yet, this is an excellent read on how to ask good questions. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx Don't be afraid to participate. Just try to improve over time. You'll come to enjoy it. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicates aren't supposed to be deleted because they contain a link to the original question.  Your other deleted question was one you deleted yourself.  I undeleted both of them.

Comment: Note taken.
I just figured, if it's a duplicate, being downvoted, and already "answered" in the related question then I should save room on the server and delete my question.

Comment: @TapThatApp The problem with question deletion is that it apparently is an extra sign for the automatic ban that you ask bad questions. (This just from experience, because I don't know the precise algorithm) So deleting them only piles extra problems onto the problem you already have. You might want to avoid that and try to rather improve as much as possible.